# Cannot resolve symbol 'menu' errors in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm learning *Android Development for Beginners* from [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837) and have completed making an app named *Court Counter* in which I wrote code for an XML (activity_main.xml) and some code for Java (MainActivity.java) file as some of the code was provided by the Udacity team on [Github](https://github.com/udacity/Court-Counter).

But when I click on 'Build APK' I get two errors both from the Java file:

1. Cannot resolve symbol 'menu' in the following code:-

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
       return true;
   }
   ```

2. Cannot resolve symbol 'action_settings':-

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       int id = item.getItemId();

       //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           return true;
       }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```

I don't know what happens when these block of code are executed but I want to run the app on my phone!

Comment: Is something coloured red? Is yes, put the cursor at it and Alt + Enter

Comment: I hope you have added appcomat's gradle to your project.

Comment: Thanks @R.Zagórski and Drv for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would have love to add this as a comment to the first answer but I can't for now; So when I had the problem using android studio 2.3. 
I clean the project and then rebuild:

**Build** --> **Clean Project** and
**Build** --> **Rebuild Project**

Comment: `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 12):

With more than 20 years of experiencie i can tell you a very difficult solution for the menu problem on android studio...:

*********** Close the project an open it again ************************

Comment: I simply cannot believe this man. You posted that a year ago. A year later I confirm that restarting the android studio fixes the problem. What a hack is going on?

Answer (score 5):

Check menu_main.xml is in your res directory. After its not working means, Once, Clear Your project.

[image]

Comment: I alt+enter on (R.menu.menu_main, menu) and then clicked on _make a menu main.xml file_ a new file was made and the error was gone. Still there is another error _Cannot resolve symbol 'action_settings'_ when I alt+enter on it it comes up with:- 1. Create id value resource 'action_settings'  2. Create field 'action_settings' 3. Rename reference. What should I do?

Comment: You should paste following lines into you menu_main.xm                       l<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.gallery.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>

Comment: Still not working. It's giving me an error in the following line: <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" android:title="@string/action_settings"/> Please state (in code format) where do I insert the lines of code. I'm a beginner!

Answer (score 3):

Try this
1) "alt+enter" (R.menu.menu_main, menu)
2) click on make a menu main.xml file (a new file)
3) Disable your antivirus
4) Run the app

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the error may arise because Android Studio failed to import R symbol.

```
import com.example.R
```