# How to add a menu folder to the res folder of an android studio project

Tags: java, android, android-layout, menu

I want to add a menu to my Android project and I created a menu folder inside the `res` folder, but got the error:

```
cannot resolve symbol 'menu'.
```

I was following an Android developers tutorial [Menus | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)

I will leave a screenshot of my project here:
[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVRf7.png)

And here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

game_menu.xml:

[game_menu.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1aOX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try clean and after rebuild project, in menu Build on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Is that how you created it? you should try.

Res -> new -> Android Resource Directory ->  Resource Type (Menu) -> Ok

Comment: I did it exactly like that

Comment: you can look at these.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43815304/8894022           https://stackoverflow.com/a/43815304/8894022

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it into one line of code like:  `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);`

First of all it is nicer coding I belive and that way we can be sure that the MenuInfalter is working. I have looked it up in my project and it is the same way there + working. If that does not help please share your game_menu.xml.

Comment: Alright and can you confirm that you put the ressource type of your Resource Directory to Menu?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your `game_menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item
           android:id="@+id/action_settings"
           android:orderInCategory="75"
           android:title="my menu Item!"
           app:showAsAction="never"/>
```